# Certain component in React is not re-rendering based on function call that changes state but other components do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this `Dashboard` component in React:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function checkSession() {
            const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
            console.log(data);
            console.log(error);
            if (data.session === null) {
                navigate("/signup");
            } 
        }

        checkSession();
    }, [navigate]);

    const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
    const [fetchingDocuments, setFetchingDocuments] = useState(true);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    async function getDocuments() {
        setFetchingDocuments(true);
        const uid = await getUserId();
        // if (uid !== null) {
        //  setUid(uid);
        // }
        console.log(uid);
        const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
            .from("pdf-documents")
            .list(uid);

        if (error !== null) throw error;

        console.log({
            "former state": documents,
            "new state": data,
        });
        setDocuments([...data]);
        setFetchingDocuments(false);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getDocuments();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <MobileSideNavigation
                sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen}
                setSidebarOpen={setSidebarOpen}
            />
            {/* Static sidebar for desktop */}

            {/* <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 bg-gray-700 p-4">
              <button className="group block w-full flex-shrink-0">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      className="inline-block h-9 w-9 rounded-full"
                      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="ml-3">
                    <p className="text-sm font-medium text-white">Tom Cook</p>
                    <p className="text-xs font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200">View profile</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </button>
            </div> */}
            <DesktopSideNavigation />
            <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col lg:pl-64">
                <div className="sticky top-0 z-10 bg-gray-100 pl-1 pt-1 sm:pl-3 sm:pt-3 lg:hidden">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="-ml-0.5 -mt-0.5 inline-flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-md text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(true)}
                    >
                        <span className="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
                        <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <main className="flex-1">
                    <div className="py-6">
                        <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                            <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">
                                Documents
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="py-2"></div>
                        <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                            <div className="flex-wrap flex items-center flex space-x-4">
                                <div className="text-center">
                                    <svg
                                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-400"
                                        fill="none"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            vectorEffect="non-scaling-stroke"
                                            strokeLinecap="round"
                                            strokeLinejoin="round"
                                            strokeWidth={2}
                                            d="M9 13h6m-3-3v6m-9 1V7a2 2 0 012-2h6l2 2h6a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2z"
                                        />
                                    </svg>
                                    {fetchingDocuments === true ? (
                                        <FetchingDocumentText />
                                    ) : (
                                        <UploadDocumentText
                                            documentLength={documents.length}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                    <div className="mt-3">
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                                            onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                                        >
                                            <PlusIcon
                                                className="-ml-0.5 mr-1.5 h-5 w-5"
                                                aria-hidden="true"
                                            />
                                            Upload Document
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <FilePickerModal
                                        open={open}
                                        setOpen={setOpen}
                                        // handleOnChange={handleDocumentsOnChange}
                                    />
                                    {/* </form> */}
                                </div>
                                {documents.map((doc) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div
                                            key={doc.id}
                                            className="border-solid border rounded-md border-gray-500 cursor-pointer hover:border-blue-500"
                                        >
                                            <ImagePreview
                                                pdf={doc}
                                                containerHeight={125}
                                                containerWidth={175}
                                                getDocuments={getDocuments}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `ImagePreview` component has modals that calls the `getDocuments` function in the `Dashboard` component:

```
function ImagePreview({ pdf, containerWidth, containerHeight, getDocuments }) {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");
    const [ellipsisModalOpen, setEllipsisModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [deleteModalOpen, setDeleteModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [renameModalOpen, setRenameModalOpen] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            try {
                const canvas = canvasRef.current;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                const uid = await getUserId();
                const publicUrl = await supabase.storage.from("pdf-documents").getPublicUrl(uid + "/" + pdf.name).data.publicUrl;

                // Load the PDF file
                pdfjsLib
                    .getDocument(publicUrl)
                    .promise.then((pdf) => {
                        // Get the specified page
                        return pdf.getPage(1);
                    })
                    .then((page) => {
                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the PDF page dimensions
                        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
                        const canvasWidth = containerWidth;
                        const canvasHeight = containerHeight;
                        const scaleX = canvasWidth / viewport.width;
                        const scaleY = canvasHeight / viewport.height;
                        const scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);
                        const newViewport = page.getViewport({ scale });

                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the fixed size
                        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
                        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

                        // Render the PDF page as an HTML5 canvas
                        const renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: newViewport,
                        };
                        page.render(renderContext);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        init();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const date = new Date(pdf.last_accessed_at);
        const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
        const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString("en-PH", options);
        setDate(dateString);

        if (pdf.name.length > 16) {
            console.log(
                {
                    "old title: ": title,
                    "new title: ": pdf.name.substring(0, 16) + " ...",
                }
            );
            setTitle(pdf.name.substring(0, 16) + " ...");
        } else {
            console.log(
                {
                    "old title: ": title,
                    "new title: ": pdf.name,
                },
            );
            setTitle(pdf.name);
        }
    }, []);

    const openEllipsisModal = () => {
        setEllipsisModalOpen(true);
    };

    const closeEllipsisModal = () => {
        setEllipsisModalOpen(false);
    };

    const openDeleteModal = () => {
        setDeleteModalOpen(true);
    };

    const closeDeleteModal = () => {
        setDeleteModalOpen(false);
    };

    const openRenameModal = () => {
        setRenameModalOpen(true);
    };

    const closeRenameModal = () => {
        setRenameModalOpen(false);
    };

    // TODO: Add OnClick event to open a new page with the pdf
    // TODO: Add a modal to delete/rename the pdf on onClick of EllipsisVerticalIcon 
    return (
        <div>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="rounded-t-md" />
            <div>
                <div className="flex flex-col p-1">
                    <p className="px-1 text-gray-900 text-sm font-semibold">
                        {title}
                    </p>
                    <div className="flex flex-row space-x-1.5">
                        <p className="py-0.5 px-1 text-gray-500 text-xs font-normal">
                            Opened {date}
                        </p>
                        <div className="relative">
                            <EllipsisVerticalIcon
                                className="h-5 w-4 text-gray-500 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-full"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                                onClick={openEllipsisModal}
                            />
                            <EllipsisModal open={ellipsisModalOpen} setClose={closeEllipsisModal} openDeleteModal={openDeleteModal} openRenameModal={openRenameModal} />
                            <DeleteModal open={deleteModalOpen} setClose={closeDeleteModal} pdfName={pdf.name} getDocuments={getDocuments}/>
                            <RenameModal open={renameModalOpen} setClose={closeRenameModal} pdfName={pdf.name} getDocuments={getDocuments}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function DeleteModal({ open, setClose, pdfName, getDocuments }) {
    async function handleDeleteOnClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const uid = await getUserId();
            const { data, error } =  await supabase.storage.from("pdf-documents").remove([uid + "/" + pdfName]);
            console.log(data, error);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
        setClose();
        await getDocuments();
    }

    return (
        <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={setClose}>
                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
                </Transition.Child>

                <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                        <Transition.Child
                            as={Fragment}
                            enter="ease-out duration-300"
                            enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                            enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                            leave="ease-in duration-200"
                            leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                            leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                        >
                            <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg sm:p-6">
                                <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 hidden pr-4 pt-4 sm:block">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="rounded-md bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
                                        onClick={setClose}
                                    >
                                        <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
                                        <XMarkIcon
                                            className="h-6 w-6"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                                    <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                                        <Dialog.Title
                                            as="h3"
                                            className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                                        >
                                            Deactivate account
                                        </Dialog.Title>
                                        <div className="mt-2">
                                            <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                                Are you sure you want to
                                                delete this reading? This action cannot be
                                                undone.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-4 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-red-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto"
                                        onClick={handleDeleteOnClick}
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto"
                                        onClick={setClose}
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Dialog.Panel>
                        </Transition.Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>
    );
}

function RenameModal({ open, setClose, pdfName, getDocuments }) {

    const [newPdfName, setNewPdfName] = useState("");

    async function handleRenameOnClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const uid = await getUserId();
            const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
                .from("pdf-documents").move(uid + "/" + pdfName, uid + "/" + newPdfName);
            console.log(data, error);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        setClose();
        await getDocuments();
    }

    const handlePdfNameOnChange = (e) => {
        const newPdfName = e.target.value;
        console.log(newPdfName);
        setNewPdfName(newPdfName);
    };

    return (
        <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={setClose}>
                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
                </Transition.Child>

                <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                        <Transition.Child
                            as={Fragment}
                            enter="ease-out duration-300"
                            enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                            enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                            leave="ease-in duration-200"
                            leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                            leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                        >
                            <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg sm:p-6">
                                <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 hidden pr-4 pt-4 sm:block">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="rounded-md bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
                                        onClick={setClose}
                                    >
                                        <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
                                        <XMarkIcon
                                            className="h-6 w-6"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                                    <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                                        <Dialog.Title
                                            as="h3"
                                            className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                                        >
                                            Rename file
                                        </Dialog.Title>
                                        <div className="mt-2">
                                            <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                                                Please enter a new name for this
                                                file:
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-5 pl-4">
                                    <form onSubmit={handleRenameOnClick}>
                                        <div className="mt-1">
                                            <input
                                                id="pdfName"
                                                onChange={handlePdfNameOnChange}
                                                name="pdfName"
                                                type="text"
                                                required
                                                className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-4 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto"
                                        onClick={handleRenameOnClick}
                                    >
                                        Rename
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto"
                                        onClick={setClose}
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Dialog.Panel>
                        </Transition.Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>
    );
}
```

When `getDocuments` is called in `DeleteModal` it causes a re-render in the `Dashboard` component's `ImagePreview` tags since the `documents` variable changed. However, when `getDocuments` is called in `RenameModal` it does not cause a re-render to the `ImagePreview` tags despite the `documents` state changing, more specifically the title isn't changed. Plus, looking into React Components viewer, the title has been changed but it isn't being displayed in the UI. Having it display on the UI requires a manual refresh of the browser. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to have only one `useEffect` in the `ImagePreview` tag and have the `pdf` prop as its dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            try {
                const canvas = canvasRef.current;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                const uid = await getUserId();
                const publicUrl = await supabase.storage.from("pdf-documents").getPublicUrl(uid + "/" + pdf.name).data.publicUrl;

                // Load the PDF file
                pdfjsLib
                    .getDocument(publicUrl)
                    .promise.then((pdf) => {
                        // Get the specified page
                        return pdf.getPage(1);
                    })
                    .then((page) => {
                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the PDF page dimensions
                        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
                        const canvasWidth = containerWidth;
                        const canvasHeight = containerHeight;
                        const scaleX = canvasWidth / viewport.width;
                        const scaleY = canvasHeight / viewport.height;
                        const scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);
                        const newViewport = page.getViewport({ scale });

                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the fixed size
                        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
                        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

                        // Render the PDF page as an HTML5 canvas
                        const renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: newViewport,
                        };
                        page.render(renderContext);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        init();
        const date = new Date(pdf.last_accessed_at);
        const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
        const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString("en-PH", options);
        setDate(dateString);

        if (pdf.name.length > 16) {
            console.log({
                "old title: ": title,
                "new title: ": pdf.name.substring(0, 16) + " ...",
            });
            setTitle(pdf.name.substring(0, 16) + " ...");
        } else {
            console.log({
                "old title: ": title,
                "new title: ": pdf.name,
            });
            setTitle(pdf.name);
        }
    }, [pdf]);
```